# Cubase LE - why don't VST instruments "stick" when recording?

Tags: audio-recording, midi, cubase

When inserting VST instruments (Halion, MT Power Drums, etc), I can hear them just fine in my monitors and all looks well. But when I record they leave only empty waveforms, and when I stop recording, that whole waveform disappears. What am I missing?

I have the track enabled, just as I do for the instruments I record (audio track recording works fine). This is Cubase LE 12.

[image]

I've gotten them to work before, but it worked with default settings. Cubase will not allow me to open both projects simultaneously to compare settings (though they look the same). I can't figure out how to get the midi "notes" to record into the track in real time.

[image]

Edit: MT Power DrumKit provides the ability to drag an assembled set of drum parts into Cubase and create the midi track in the second screenshot, above.

Comment: "when I record" - how are you recording? These instruments aren't routed to an audio track; they're driven by midi & the audio is generated 'live' at each pass. To record the result, you either Freeze or bounce-in-place. [It's been so long since I used Cubase, you'll have too look in the manual for where these options are.]

Comment: I've done this before without the defaults and didn't have to bounce-in-place. That's a great suggestion, but not really the answer ;-)

Comment: This bit is worrying… *"can't figure out how to get the midi "notes" to record into the track in real time"* That's not really how you do it. You just bounce it. To do it your way, you'd have to route the o/p of your VSTi to an audio track input. Not something I've ever tried.

Comment: There has to be a waveform present to bounce it? without a waveform selected "bounce" is grayed out. The midi "notes" are not showing up (see the second screenshot, above).

Comment: No, you don't need a waveform - a VSTi doesn't produce a waveform, because it has no audio path except out to the mixer. Sorry, but without being able to see over your shoulder, I cannot figure out if it's something you've done, or something not behaving. I suspect you're hoping for a routing to an input, that simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes. I seemed to have changed some global routing option for VST instruments. Now it doesn't work anywhere. I did not have to re-route, before. In the second screenshot above, the VST drums are leaving "some track with midi marks in it". It's not a waveform, but it's creating a playable track in the project. That no longer happens.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I'm back to "I cannot see over your shoulder" to know what you did.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're confused about how MIDI works. If you want to record a VSTi, you need to record the output of Cubase as an input on an audio track (unless that's changed). You usually just bounce or freeze until mixdown. I haven't used Cubase for a while either, though, but I used to record DSP effects by feeding Cubase's output back to an input after adding the DSP effect bus. But I had good ASIO routing software/drivers. But if I just wanted to free resources, I'd freeze or bounce.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://forums.steinberg.net/t/not-recording-vst-halion-se-in-ce6/629646/7), in the form of the *virtual keyboard*. I don't fully understand the answer yet but it does work and gives me a place to start w/r/t learning how MIDI works.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer suffers from similar to the question - it's just a link to a long discussion & doesn't really answer the question. We'd again have to be able to see over your shoulder to see what you were doing wrong & how you fixed it. I could hazard a guess that it was because you expected clicking on a keyboard on the VSTi to record its output…

Comment: I agree. I am tempted to delete it.

Comment: HOLD. UP. You were asking about recording **audio**, That post is talking about recording MIDI. That's right, right? Or have I missed something here?

Comment: You are correct. Even though I know the difference, I was conflating the two in my question.